# Why the time complexity of this function is not O(m!)?

Tags: c, function, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

When I try to find the time complexity of this function, I come with `m!`.
What I did is

```
T(n,m)=m*T(n-1,m-1)=m(m-1)T(n-2,m-2)=....=m!T(1,1)
```

but the answer of the time complexity is `O(n)`. Why?

```
void f3 (int n, int m)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return;
    if (m > 1)
        return m*f3(n-1, m-1);
    f3(n-1, m);
}
```

Comment: `return m*f3(n-1, m-1);` - how can it return anything if it is `void`?

Comment: Your return type has an inconsistency. (i.e. you are returning void in some cases and a non-void value in another) You should correct/clarify those so that people may gain a proper insight as to the source of your issue, rather than guessing what you intended to achieve.

Comment: What source states O(n) ?

Comment: Your mistake is in writing down `T(n,m)=m*T(n-1,m-1)` -- note that computing `m*f3(n-1, m-1)` does not take `m` times the time to compute `f3(n-1, m-1)`: that's the relation between the **values**, not the time taken to **compute** them. Instead, you'll get the correct answer if you correctly write down `T(n,m)= 1 + T(n-1,m-1)` -- the time taken to compute `m*f3(n-1, m-1)` is the time to compute `f3(n-1, m-1)`, plus a single operation to multiply the result by the value `m`.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I get it  but why it is 1+T(n-1,m-1) instead of T(n-1,m-1)? where the **"1"** come from?

Comment: @sam0101 To multiply the result (return value of the function) by a number, it takes one additional operation. (This is if we're counting arithmetic operations; in practice on a computer there's some cost of the function call, which can actually be greater than the cost of a multiply, but we generally ignore such details as they don't matter asymptotically)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR great explanation, Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The recursion termination depends on `n`: `if (n <= 1) return;`
- There are 2 possible recursive calls: `m*f3(n-1, m-1)` or `f3(n-1, m)`. (either one or the other)

The argument `n` is decremented after each call. As a consequence, there will be at most `n` calls to the function `f3`.

The time complexity of the remain of the function `f3` is constant. The total time complexity is then `O(n)`.

I'd recommend you to add a `printf` statement at the begin of the function to print all the calls. That will help you to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

The function decrement *n* and call itself another time, so there are *N* call of the function *f* that has `O(1)` complexity, so `NO(1)=O(N)`. Your mistake is to consider *m*f(n-1,m-1)* as *M* call of the function *F*.

Comment: bug it also decrements m so what about that? If m>1 ---> f(n-1,m-1)..!!!? what I missing here?

Comment: If you follow the code you simple return 3*what your next call return. If your algorithm is each call you make 3 call of the function f(n-1,m-1) then is another story, and the analysis is a little bit more complicated but not to hard

Comment: You confuse the decrement of M, m is just a parameter to decide wich parameter return and not if continue or not the recursion

Comment: @sam0101 You're missing the fact that `n` is more important than `m`.  For example, consider `f3(3, 10000)`. What's going to happen? `n` will get decremented twice, and then is doesn't matter what `m` is, because the first `if` will cause the function to return.

Answer (score 1):

**The return value does not tell anything about the complexity of the function.**
Complexity tells about how many steps will it take to run the code.

Notice that

- f3(n, m) = 0 if n <= 0
- f3(n, m) = f3(n-1, m-1) if m > 1
- f3(n, m) = f3(n-1, m) if m = 1
- f3(n, m) = 0 otherwise

In the 1st case the solution happens in 1 step.

In second case the problem gets converted into 1st case or 3rd and then 1st case depending upon value of m. However this will always happen in O(n). If m is greater O(n) to 1st case else O(n) until n becomes 1.

In 3rd case the problem will get converted to 1st case in O(n).

4th case in O(1).

Hence the problem is a O(n) problem.